# Can't rewind WWDC 2021 on youtube livestream nor on youtube

Tags: macos

This is really annoying I wanted to start watching while the event was one hour in but I can't find any way to start over from the start...

Is there a dvr / TiVo solution for these or do I need to wait for the full video to be posted later?

Answer (score 1):

Live streams are not random access past a short buffering period.

I've never watched it on YouTube, only ever directly from Apple, but that's always been the case. In essence, it's 'live' until it's over.

Comment: In other words, you have to watch in on Apple's terms.